# Pass fetched data to react component

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am fetching data in the server side using getServerSideProps. the data fetching is working well. I want to pass the fetched data to a component called UserForm. This is my code

```
// This gets called on every request
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    // Fetch data from external API
    const { id } = context.query;
    const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3001/v1/firm/${id}`)
    const data = await res.json()

    // Pass data to the page via props
    return { props: { data } }
}

function ComingSoon({ data }) {

    const router = useRouter()
    const { id } = router.query

    return (
        <div className="coming-soon-area">
            <TopHeader />
            <NavbarStyleFive />
            <UserForm data = {data}/>
            <Footer />
        </div>
    )
}

export default ComingSoon;
```

And this is the content of UserForm

```
import React from 'react';
const UserForm = (data) => {
    return (
        <div className="coming-soon-area">
            <h2>{data[0].name} coming soon</h2>
        </div>
    )
}
export default UsernForm;
```

I get an error in UserForm telling me that data is undefined. Any idea about the problem?

**EDIT:**
Data is not undefined, this code works fine. I think the problem is accessing the data props in UserForm

```
    <div className="coming-soon-area">
        <TopHeader />
        <NavbarStyleFive />
        <h2>{data[0].name} coming soon</h2>
        <Footer />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering that `data` from api comes async, React could try to render `UserForm` before `data` are available. To avoid this, you could just modify `UserForm` like:

```
import React from 'react';
  const UserForm = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <div className="coming-soon-area">
        {data && data.length > 0 && <h2>{data[0].name} sofort kündigen</h2>}
    </div>
  )
}
export default UsernForm;
```

In this way, only if `data` are valid and not empty, `data[0].name` will be displayed.

Comment: the app is not crashing anymore but unfortunately data[0].name is never displayed, so the value of data seems to be always null on the component.

Comment: And the api call is done on the server side, so data can not be empty when displayed to the user ;)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't see `data` shape. But try something like `data.data` (usually is somthing like this...).

Comment: If I remove data from "const UserForm = (data) => {" data is undefined. So I think I am accessing data in the wrong way in UserForm

Comment: Yes I'm thinking the same. Can you show me `data` console.log?

Comment: can attach data's shape after console.log it?

Comment: I updated my answer, maybe is a destructuring problem (I added bracket between `data`)

Answer (score 0):

Always consider checking fetched data before you access it.
`data` is initially `undefined` i.e. in initial `mount`.
And, when an `undefined`, empty or null value is not expected, you have plenty of ways to prevent this. You can use a conditional statement or even [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)